7 students in 4 desks
There are 7 students who need to be seated at 4 desks arranged in a row, each desk having 2 seats. The left seat of each desk must always be occupied. In how many ways can this arrangement be done?
My attempt:
Let's name the students A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and the empty seats K. Clearly in each arrangement we have one K.
If there was no restriction, we would have $8!$ ways in total.
However, K cannot be in positions 1, 3, 5 or 7.
Therefore the total ways are $\frac {8!}{2}$, that is, 20160.
Is this correct?
Is there any other way to solve it?
For example, to first select
Thank you.

It is correct.
As an alternative approach, select the empty seat from the $4$ right-side possibilities and then seat the seven students in the remaining seats in one of the $7!$ orders, giving $4 \times 7!=20160$.  In effect you choose the empty seat $K$ before the others.
Both approaches are correct, and you have $\frac{8!}2=4 \times 7!$.
